# How to create a custom PopupMenu in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, popupmenu

How can I replicate something like I made below in Balsamiq?

I made this menu, but it is only displaying the text of the items (not the icons). Is it possible to display both the title and icon in a PopupMenu?

Here is my `create_post_menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_photo"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera"
        android:title="@string/action_photo"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_video"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_video"
        android:title="@string/action_video"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_text"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
        android:title="@string/action_text"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_link"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_web_site"
        android:title="@string/action_link"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText" />

</menu>
```

[image: A]

**Edit**

Here are my `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` methods:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_new) {
        View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.action_new);
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView);
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.create_post_menu);
        popupMenu.show();
        return true;
    } else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_search) {
        return true;
    } else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
        return true;
    } else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_help) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using AppCompact library for ActionBar  ?

Comment: @Ye Lin Aung No, I'm not.

Comment: Can you post your onCreateOptionsMenu() method?

Comment: @LazyNinja I just did.

Comment: I've trie several ways but still can't get it right. Interesting.

Comment: It is not an easy task http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805756/is-it-possible-to-display-icons-in-a-popupmenu @YeLinAung

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I resolved this issue by simply putting the `create_post_menu` inside of the `item` whose icon is a `+`.

For example, I have (using AppCompat):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_new"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
            android:title="@string/action_new"
            app:showAsAction="always">

            <menu>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/action_photo"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera"
                    android:title="@string/action_photo"
                    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/action_video"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_video"
                    android:title="@string/action_video"
                    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/action_text"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_text"
                    android:title="@string/action_text"
                    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/action_place"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_place"
                    android:title="@string/action_place"
                    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/action_more"
                    android:title="@string/action_more"
                    android:visible="false"
                    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />

            </menu>
        </item>
        ...(more menu items here)
</menu>
```

Without AppCompat, you could just get rid of the XML Namespace `app` by replacing `app` with `android`.

Comment: What is the use of `xmlns:app`?

Answer (score 12):

```
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.view.MenuItem;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.PopupMenu;  
import android.widget.Toast;  
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
Button button1;  

         @Override  
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

          button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);//your created butto
          button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

           @Override  
           public void onClick(View v) {  
            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu  
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button1);  
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file  
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());  

            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener  
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
             public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
              return true;  
             }  
            });  

            popup.show();//showing popup menu  
           }  
          });//closing the setOnClickListener method  
         }  
    }
```

Comment: your code is working but Its showing only Titles, how I can achieve titles with icons? any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

I hope my previous answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293980/show-popup-menu-when-action-bar-item-is-clicked/23950809#23950809) can help you.
If you just want a similar popup menu, you can use ActionProvider. It's more powerful.
If you want it as a true menu, you can use custom PopupMenu.

Comment: Do you know of any resources where I can see a complete example of this?

Comment: @lschlessinger Just take a look at Android developer guide, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to implement this. Very frustrating that their example from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#CreatingActionProvider) `ActionBarSettingsActionProviderActivity` doesn't exist.

Comment: @lschlessinger  Yes, the link has been moved, you can check these samples: http://developer.android.com/samples/ActionBarCompat-Basic/index.html