# Overflow Menu icon issue Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to display action overflow menu with icons in my one application. I am not getting icons in menu. My Target SDK is 23 and minimum SDK is 15.

[image]

My Menu.XML is like belwo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<!-- Single menu item
     Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
-->
<item android:id="@+id/menu_donate"
      android:icon="@drawable/new_facebook_page"
      android:title="@string/facebook"
      app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/new_facebook_page" 
      android:title="@string/facebook"
      app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
      android:icon="@drawable/new_facebook_page"
      android:title="@string/facebook" 
      app:showAsAction="never" />

      </menu>
```

My Java code is like below.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: The overflow menu does not show icons.

Comment: Only the menu items which are configured to be shown as action can be shown with icons.

Comment: @jaibatrik can you please explain little more ?

Comment: I think you'll want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374183/how-to-show-icons-in-overflow-menu-in-actionbar

Comment: it can be done by overriding `onPrepareOptionsPanel` .. see the answers to the question linked by REG1.

Answer (score 0):

the overflow menu doesn't show icons (as CommonsWare said). Anyway you can use this workaround:
create an option menu with just one item with the "overflow three dots" icon. When selected, you just show a popupmenu as described here:

[How to create a custom PopupMenu in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400732/how-to-create-a-custom-popupmenu-in-android)

I hope it helped.